# Error on AJAX call:Error: NetworkError: DOM Exception 19

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

Got this error while making an cross domain ajax request.

*Error: NetworkError: DOM Exception 19*

Please help on this . Stuck real bad :(

Comment: What browser are you using? For example, Chrome has a problems with the policy in cross domain..

Comment: am getting this problem in chrome. But seems like the same issue is there in the Firefox as well

Comment: Am planning to switch it over to JSONP instead of ajax. Will that help me ? Because in Mozilla FF it says 

**"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden "**

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when using synchronous requests in Chrome:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", url, false) // false denotes synchronous call
req.send();
```

Doing it asynchronous (which I wanted to anyways) didn't give me the error.

I then discovered that the server rewrote the URL. If I used the rewritten URL, I didn't get the error. Probably a Chrome bug, since Safari handles the synchronous, non-rewritten case just fine.

Don't know if I'll report it, since synchronous XMLHttpRequests are deprecated anyways.

Answer (score 1):

A common error is to send a https request on a server that's expecting a http connection.

Answer (score 1):

To get cross-domain AJAX calls to work, I have used PHP on the server ...

getRemoteUrl.php

```
<?php
if (preg_match("/^[();[]{}]+$/", $_GET['url'])) {
  //Something bad
} else {
  $ctx = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('timeout' => 10)));

  if (!(@$contents = file_get_contents($_GET['url'], 0, $ctx))) {
    //fail
  } else {
    //success
    echo $contents;
  }
}
?>
```

then call the PHP file and use the output as if you called the website directly.

```
function GetXmlHttpObject() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
  // code for IE6, IE5
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  } else {
   return null;
  }
}

var xmlhttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp === null) {
  //Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!
} else {
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "getRemoteUrl.php" + "?url=someRemoteUrl", false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  var webpage = xmlhttp.responseText;
  //do something with webpage
}
```

I would recommend using asynchronous instead; I used synchronous for brevity.
This can be done with other server-side languages if PHP is not preferred or available.

Answer (score 0):

DOM Exception 19 refers to a "Network Error". Is the URL that you are contacting in your Ajax call available?

Cross domain requests are possible if the server supports it! Before making the actual GET/POST call, the browser issues an OPTIONS call to the server to check whether it supports cross domain requests. Check if the server that you are contacting supports cross domain requests.
For more details on cross domain requests refer to this article which is very helpful: [Using CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-introduction)

Answer (score 0):

to avoid the cross-domain policy of a server you can use [Korz](https://github.com/TOMODOcom/TOMODOkorz), just add

```
<script src="//tomodo-tools.s3.amazonaws.com/tomodo.korz-0.5.js"></script>
```

to your `<head>` and all cross domain requests will be routed througth [tomodo.me](//tomodo.com) so their `Access-Control-Allow-Origin header` is '*'.

Comment: it doesn't work! do you know if any other service provide such thing?